# Multi-line in curl command

Tags: curl, web

How can I pass the following block of text using the curl command?

```
Hello, world
I am new
```

Notice there is a new line in the text block.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8014/?text=
```

How do I frame my curl command to pass the above block of text as the query parameter for text?

Comment: You need to **urlencode** your text - this will not only remove the newlines, but fix up the complete text in a way, that makes it fit for transmission as a GET parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding and sending data will do.

```
Hello, world
I am new
```

will be encoded to:

```
Hello%2C%20world%0AI%20am%20new
```